# How can I remove the padding on pages on mobile only

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

Hello I cannot figure out how to remove the borders on my website in mobile only. I have huge padding that do not look good in mobile.

An example page
https://www.onlinematching.games/jewels-blitz/

Comment: Please share which borders are you talking about , Please share exact screenshot or problem . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS media queries.

You can control design for different devices using media queries.

Reference:- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 1):

as I checked your site all you have to do is change the `width` attribute of `.container, .container-1400` in your style. there are more than one place to be changed(for every media queries).

codes below are for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px){
    .container, .container-1400{ width : 99%;/* 1% for margin */}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But that did not work... I’m still getting a lot of extra space in Mobil in portrait view